# How to alter a views result in drupal 8?

Tags: 8, entities, views

## Description:

I have 3 content types:

- A `property`, that has for example a field `address` and a field "`number_of_rooms`"
- A `property_type`, that is like an *abstract* property, having also `number_of_rooms`, but no `address`, because it belongs to...
- A `development`, that has a number of property types and an `address`

I want to do a search over `properties` or `property_types`, filtering by `number_of_rooms`, but displaying the related development if the result is a `property_type` and without duplicates.

## Example:

- Home | 2 rooms | Address 1 | type: `property`
- Greentree Urbanization | Address 2 | type: `development`

  - Type A | 2 rooms | type: `property_type`
  - Type B | 3 rooms | type: `property_type`

I want to search for "rooms < 4" and the results should be something like this:

- Home | 2 rooms | Address 1 | type: `property`
- Greentree Urbanization | 2, 3 rooms | Address 2 | type: `development`

## What I did:

I was able to create a view that shows all the results for the `property` and `property_type` content types, showing also the referenced `development` but with duplicates. Like this:

- Home | 2 rooms | Address 1 | type: `property`
- Type A | 2 rooms | type: `property_type`

  - Greentree Urbanization | Address 2 | type: `development`
- Type B | 3 rooms | type: `property_type`

  - Greentree Urbanization | Address 2 | type: `development`

I now want to alter the view results *merge* the `developments` so they only appear once. I created a module with a hook_view_pre_render().

- How do I create and render what I want?
- Do I need a custom entity?
- How do I output this to the twig template?

Or maybe there is another way to do this that I couldn't think of...

Comment: Have you considered making property_type a taxonomy vocabulary instead of a content type?

Comment: The property_type has its own attributes, and I need to use those on the searches.

Comment: You can add fields to taxonomy vocabularies as well...

Comment: I didn't know that, but even so, how do I search for items containing a taxonomy term with `rooms = 3` ?